# What kind of triangle / ruler is shown in this video?

Tags: sketching, tool-identification

https://youtu.be/p8LBr6cZPuY?t=530

At roughly the timestamp above the architect uses an odd looking metal straightedge and I was wondering what it was called. I thought it was a regular architect's scale at first, but two of the fins are small. I can't make out any brand marks and have so far had no luck finding out what it is.

Have any of you seen something similar?

[image: Picture]

Comment: The only thing that seems to match your description is the "ruler/triangle" segment at time 8:50.  Is that what you're referring to?  I haven't seen one like the one shown there.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm referring to.

Comment: Please add an image of the tool you're looking for. Videos can be removed and links can die.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s a ‘Brown + Sharpe toolmakers knife-edge #530’

In the video he was probably just referring to the second ruler he showed with the bevelled edge.